# Failure in Calling a Function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function that compares two matrices. It will compare the element of both matrices at a certain position, and returns "greater than" "equal to" or "less than". Below is the code I have right now. However, when I tried calling the function, R does not return anything, not even an error message. I'm wondering why that is the case. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

```
fxn <- function(x, y) {
  emptymatrix <- matrix( , nrow = dim(x)[1], ncol = dim(x)[2])
  for (i in 1:dim(emptymatrix)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(emptymatrix)[2]) {
      if (x[i, j] < y[i, j]) {
        emptymatrix[i, j] <- "Less Than"
      }else if (x[i, j] == y[i, j]) {
        emptymatrix[i, j] <- "Equal to"
      }else {
        emptymatrix[i, j] <- "Greater than"
      }
    }
  }
}

#trying to test the function
vecc1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
vecc2 <- c(4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 9, 10)
matrix1 <- matrix(vecc1, nrow = 3, byrow = T)
matrix2 <- matrix (vecc2, nrow=3, byrow = T)
fxn(matrix1, matrix2)
```

Comment: The answer is about the return value - but you know with matrices the same size you can create a boolean matrix of greater/less than comparisons without a loop, e.g. with `matrix1>matrix2`? In R, you very rarely need to write the sort of nested loops you commonly see in languages like `C`. And they will generally be very slow compared to solutions that avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi as SamR pointed out in his comment, your function doesn't return anything, because it has no return function / object in the end. He is also right about the loop thing, because R is mainly designed for tabular data and matrices it can do a lot of stuff for you under the hood. This is a great examples about some design principles R has. First we don't need to use a for loop because we can just evaluate larger equal less, on all indices (vectorized). The output will be a matrix of size M with TRUE / FALSE. we can use this matrix to index our new matrix at all TRUE position. than we just need to assign a single string "equal", "larger", or "less" that gets recycled to the length of the longer vector(/list).

```
vecc1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
vecc2 <- c(4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 9, 10)
matrix1 <- matrix(vecc1, nrow = 3, byrow = T)
matrix2 <- matrix (vecc2, nrow=3, byrow = T)

# run this to see how the comparision works
matrix1 == matrix2

foo <- function(x,y) {
  m_new<-matrix(NA,nrow=dim(x),ncol=dim(x))
  m_new[x==y]<-"Equal"
  m_new[x<y]<-"Less Than"
  m_new[x>y]<-"Greater Than"
  m_new # faster 
  #return(m_new) is not as efficent
}

foo(matrix1,matrix2)
```

Comment: wow hi akrun did i miss anything=?

Comment: Because there were several comments from KonradRudolph below my post regarding the `return`, so I decided to delete my post.   Just wonder whether he approves this or not.

Comment: @user12256545:  I'd avoid using `return()` when you don't have to.  It's a little bit inefficient.

Comment: I never knew, will adapt to my code in the future!

Comment: It can also be a little dangerous, because you might be tempted to type `return;` as the last statement when you don't want to return a value.  That doesn't do anything like it would in many other languages.

Comment: i think it depends, while it feels a litte redundant to call a return function just to return one object it also makes the code clearer, for example if there are multiple possible return states,

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple places in a function where you want to bail out, then calling `return(value)` is one way to do it, and it might be the best one.  But it's generally good to try to limit the number of places where you can return, because that often makes the logic of the function easier to understand.  One exception is a very early return to bail out without doing anything:  that's better than `if (simple) simpleAnswer else { very long answer }`.

Comment: Another reason not to use `return(value)` at the end of a function is that it would make me as a reader of that function wonder if there are other `return()` calls somewhere earlier.  Make your functions easy to understand.

Comment: The tidyverse R style guide advocates for implicit returns. The [Google R style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html) disagrees.

Answer (score 0):

You missed returning `emptyMatrix` from your function.

In R, the result of the last statement in a function is returned automatically. In the original function, the last statement was the `for` loop, whose value is NULL. It was returned, marked "invisible", so it didn't print.

The usual convention in R is to type the name of the object you want to return when it isn't already the last value produced.  So just add one line to your function, containing `emptyMatrix`.

You can also call `return(emptyMatrix)`, but that's actually less efficient.

And if you like returning things invisibly like `for` loops do, you can call `invisible(emptyMatrix)` as the last line.  Then it won't automatically print, but you can still assign it to another variable.